# Why has the Sitecore proposal been in Beta for over 890 days?

Tags: discussion, public-beta

I just noticed the Sitecore Q&A proposal has been in Beta for 891 days, when is it going to be approved as a full member of SE? and what are the requirements to get out of Beta?

[image: 9]

Comment: If it might make you feel better, [Board and Card Games](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220/board-and-card-games) is still in beta after 3000 days, and [no new sites have graduated since Oct 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290363/241919).

Comment: A note for posterity: [Sitecore.SE left beta in December 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/335251).

Answer (score 3):

A simple question with no simple answers :-)

For starters, see the discussion here: [Should we rename or remove the "beta" label?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257652/should-we-rename-or-remove-the-beta-label/257747#257747)

But the general indicators are:

1) Needs to have a healthy active community so proper moderator elections can take place
2) Needs to have 10 questions a day consistently

Additional information here: [Graduation, site closure, and a clearer outlook on the health of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites)

As far as Sitecore Stack Exchange goes, we are definitely at or very near the graduation point.